# java LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, hash, scjp, linkedhashset

I've been studying for OCJP (former SCJP) and I came across the following example which uses LinkedHashSet:

```
public class Test{

    int size;

    public Test(int s){
       this.size = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         return (this.size == ((Test)obj).size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      LinkedHashSet<Test> s = new LinkedHashSet<Test>();
      s.add(new Test(1));
      s.add(new Test(2));
      s.add(new Test(1));
      System.out.println(s.size());
    }
}
```

Now, the question is what is displayed if :
1) implementation stays as is
2) override of hashCode is inserted in the class Test as follows:

```
public int hashCode() {return size/5};
```

Running and compiling the code states that the size of set in the first case is 3, while in the second it is 2.
Why?

In case 1, although equals method is overriden, it is never invoked. Does that mean that add() method does not check for object equality if hashCode method is not overriden?
In case 2, hashCode with the given implementation and the give set of Test objects always returns the same number. How is that different from the default hashCode implementation, and why does it cause equals to be invoked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't override `hashCode()`, then each of your instances will have *hashcode* calculated from some pre-defined *Hashing algorithm* in `Object` class. So, all your instances will possibly have *different hashcode* values (This is not for sure though). Means, each instance will go into its own *bucket*.

Now, even if you overridden `equals()` method make two instances equal based on some attribute, their *hashcodes* are still different.

So, two instances with a different hashcodes, can never be equal. So the *size of the set* is 3. Since it does not have any duplicate.

---

But, when you override `hashCode()` with following implementation: -

```
public int hashCode() {return size/5};
```

It will return same value for same `size`. So the instances with same value of `size` will have same *hashcodes* and also, since you have compared them in `equals` method on the basis of `size`, so they will be `equal` and hence they will be considered duplicate in your `Set` and hence will be removed.So, `Set.size()` is 2.

**Moral**: - You should always override `hashCode()` whenever you override `equals()` method, to maintain the general contract between the two methods.

**General contract between `hashcode` and `equals` method**: -

- When two objects are equal, their hashcode must be equal
- When two objects are not equal, their hashcode can be equal
- The hashCode algorithm should always generate same value for same object.
- If hashCode for two objects are different, they will not be equal
- Always use `same attributes` to calculate `hashCode` that you used to compare the two instances

**Strongly suggested to read at least once**: -

- [**`Effective Java -
  Item#9: Always override hashCode when you override equals`**](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/methods-common-to-all-objects/ch03lev1sec2)

Comment: So, simplified, when default hashCode implementation is used, every object is in its own "bucket". Since there is only one object in the bucket, there is nothing to compare it with, so it is just added to a collection? I think I'm starting to get it.

Comment: @Maggie. I suggest you to read that last link I gave. That gives the best explanation about this topic.

Comment: Yes, yes, I have that book also, and I think I read it a while ago, but this collection / generics topic just gives me too much headache.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Maggie. You're welcome. And don't let that book lost in some dark room. That's worth reading 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

Hashing structures rely on hashing algorithm which is represented by `hashCode()` in java. When you put something into a `HashMap` (or `LinkedHashSet` in your case), jvm invokes `hashCode()` on the objects that are being inserted into this structure. When it is not overriden, default `hashCode()` from `Object` class will be used and it is way inefficient -- all the objects get into their own buckets.

When you override the `hashCode()` the way that is shown in your example, all of objects in your example will get into the same bucket. And then (when adding them one after another), be compared with `equals()`. That's why in the first case (when `equals()` is not called) you get size of 3, and in the second -- 2.